# Filtering list of dataframes based on the number of observations in each dataframe

Tags: r, purrr

Say you've got list of dataframes:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

dat <- map(mtcars, tabyl)
```

How could you then filter out those dataframes with more than 6 observations?

My first thought was `discard()` but I have had no such luck. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: `dat[lapply(dat, nrow) > 6]`

Comment: No such luck how? What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: @camille Wouldn't this be a dupe?

Comment: @akrun that's totally possible. If you have one, marking as such would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `purrr::discard`

```
purrr::discard(dat, ~nrow(.) < 6)
```

or with `keep`

```
purrr::keep(dat, ~nrow(.) >= 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sapply` to create a logical vector and use that to filter the `list` in `base R` (no packages used)

```
dat[sapply(dat, nrow) >= 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Filter`, i.e.

```
Filter(function(i)nrow(i) >= 6, dat)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `purrr` variant:

```
dat[purrr::map_lgl(dat,~nrow(.x)>=6)]
```